# How can I update a page in real time in reaction to database changes?

Tags: php, ajax, database, vs-web-site-project

Thanks for helping.
I have no formal experience with web design and would like to consult experienced individuals for design recommendations rather than devising a convoluted solution myself. In a current project, I must prompt GUI updates to a webpage in response to every column altercation within a database.
I have found several recommendations for similar problems, but remain too inexperienced to truly understand whether each is viable for my specific issue or how to fully follow through with each.

In brief, how should I go about completing this task? Thanks again.

Comment: If you already found a solution, it is likely that we will also recommend those solutions to you. What are those solutions then?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

1. Ajax
2. Web-Socket

Choose which is suitable for you,

**AJAX**

Ajax is a `front-end` based technology to make `HTTP-Request` to server asynchronously.
AJAX Request will not reload or redirect your page. It will handle request and response in background.

Mostly using for working with database without refreshing site again and again & also for frequent requests.

**Web-Socket**

This is a `Socket-Connection` Between `Client` & `Server`. Also using `TCP` instead of `HTTP`.

This technology very famous for `Real-Time Application Development` like continuously changing data/graphs , Chat / Messaging Applications & Etc.

**Useful links**

[Websocket tutorial](https://www.xul.fr/en/html5/websocket.php)

[AJAX Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/)

Comment: Actually to transfer sensitive information securely, over internet or network, You should use `SSL` and proper dedicated `encryption`.

Comment: How specifcally could I employ AJAX to provide messages from databases? Would I just create a PHP page to check on an infinite loop, create an XHTTP connection via AJAX, and receive messages when an update occurs? Is there a better approach?